# Установка Qt 4.8.5 для VS2015

Tags: qt, visual-studio, visual-c++

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь собрать **Qt 4.8.5** средствами компилятора **VS 2015**. 
Как основной вариант использую алгоритм предложенный тут: [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848962/how-to-build-qt-4-8-6-with-visual-studio-2015-without-official-support).

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Создаю папку `C:\Qt\4.8.5`
2. Скачиваю и распаковываю в эту папку архив с `Qt 4.8.5` ( [qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.zip](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.5/))
3. Устанавливаю python patch для чего в cmd набираю команды: `pip install patch` и `-m patch`.
4. Скачал `02-fix_build_with_msvc2015-45e8f4ee.diff` (Как в оригинале [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848962/how-to-build-qt-4-8-6-with-visual-studio-2015-without-official-support)) и скопировал его в папку `C:\Qt\4.8.5`
5. В ту же папку (`C:\Qt\4.8.5`) скопировал `patch.py` из папки (`C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\`).
6. Захожу в командную строку находясь в папке `C:\Qt\4.8.5` и выполняю команду `patch.py 02-fix_build_with_msvc2015-45e8f4ee.diff`.
7. Удаляю `patch.py` из директории `C:\Qt\4.8.5`
8. Создаю новую директорию `win32-msvc2015` в директории `C:\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs` и копирую в нее все содержимое папки `win32-msvc2012`.
9. Редактирую в созданной папке `win32-msvc2015` содержимой файла`qmake.conf`:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
10. Перехожу в папку `C:\Qt\4.8.5\qmake` для редактирования файла `Makefile.win32`:
    [image: Первая правка]
    [image: Вторая правка]
11. После этого запускаю `Visual Studio 2015 command prompt` и перехожу в папку `C:\Qt\4.8.5`.
12. Ввожу в `Visual Studio 2015 command prompt` команду `configure -platform win32-msvc2015 -prefix C:\Qt-2015\4.8.5\msvc2015`

И получаю:

[image: Ошибка]

**И как обойти эту ошибку пока не понял.**

P.S. Если что, еще стоят нужные переменные окружения `QTDIR=B:\Qt\4.8.5`, `QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2015`, Добавляем `%QTDIR%\bin` в начало `PATH`.

Comment: Если Вы делает по инструкции, то где у Вас в команде `-make nmake`?

Comment: Так же там в комментариях упоминают, что 4.8.7 поддерживает VS2015, или Вам принципиально нужна 4.8.5? Там же только багфиксы, вроде.

Comment: @ ixSci Да, нужна принципиально Qt 4.8.5. К счастью я уже нашел решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для настройки используются решения предлагаемые по ссылкам [Ссылка1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848962/how-to-build-qt-4-8-6-with-visual-studio-2015-without-official-support) и [Ссылка2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080625/qt-4-8-visual-studio-2013-compiling-error/19454490#19454490).

Алгоритм настроек такой:

1. Сначала делаем все действия по [Первой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848962/how-to-build-qt-4-8-6-with-visual-studio-2015-without-official-support) до строки с `configure` (Пункт 5 по ссылке)
2. Ставим переменные окружения: `PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin;`, `QMAKESPEC = win32-msvc2015` и `QTDIR = C:\Qt\4.8.5\`.
3. Делаем все действия по [Второй ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080625/qt-4-8-visual-studio-2013-compiling-error/19454490#19454490)
4. В консоли VS2015 в папке куда распаковывали Qt прописываем `configure -make nmake -platform win32-msvc2015` (Пункт 5 первой ссылки).
5. В консоли VS2015 в папке куда распаковывали Qt прописываем `nmake` и ждем часа полтора (Пункт 6 первой ссылки).